# Clone Power BI Dataflow from to another Workspace

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to export a Dataflow from one workspace so that it can be uploaded into a new workspace and have its parameters changed.

I can get the dataflow as JSON using this API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows/get-dataflow

This returns the dataflow as JSON, which I then want to import into a new workspace after some processing.

This API seems most promising but keeps failing with 400 Bad Request using either the JSON in body as application/json content-type or using the multipart/form-data type and passing it in that way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/post-import-in-group

```
param(
    [string]$SourceWorkspaceId = "guid1",
    [string]$TargetWorkspaceId = "guid2",
    [string]$DataflowId = "guid3",
    [string]$AccessToken = "stringoftoken"
)

function Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Method,
        [string]$Body,
        [string]$ContentType
    )
    
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $AccessToken"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }

    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method $Method -Headers $headers -Body $Body -UseBasicParsing

    return $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
}

$apiRootUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg"

# Retrieve the dataflow from the source workspace
$dataflowUrl = "$apiRootUrl/groups/$SourceWorkspaceId/dataflows/$DataflowId"
$sourceDataflow = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $dataflowUrl -Method "GET"

# Read the JSON dataflow file content
# $jsonData = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw
$sourceDataflow.name
# Create the import URL
$importUrl = "$apiRootUrl/groups/$TargetWorkspaceId/imports?datasetDisplayName=SynapseDataflow"

# Upload the JSON dataflow file to Power BI
$response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $importUrl -Method "POST" -Body $sourceDataflow -ContentType "application/json"

Write-Output "Import ID: $($response.id)"
Write-Output "Status: $($response.importState)"
```

Is it possible my issue is that I am not passing the JSON correctly in to the body when uploading? Or is there a better way to achieve this via the API?

Thanks,

Comment: Error 400 is  a general error indicating the request is bad.  It could be a parameter in the URL, and HTTP Header or the Body.  With JSON the body is an entire JSON message.  There are online checkers to make sure the JSON is valid.  Your links have very good samples.  Best way of finding issue is to debug the server code.  Add break point and then find out why it is failing.

Comment: It was something to do with the body, in the end I used a library where they seem to call the same API but with some pre-processing on file. It is working for me now but I had hoped there was a simple API call I could use. Here is the link for anyone that might have similar problem. 

https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/tree/master/examples/dataflows